# Cannot encrypt password in configuration file

Tags: java, hibernate, encryption, jasypt

I'm having trouble encrypting the database password in `hibernate.cfg.xml`

This is my property file.

```xml
<!-- Database connection settings -->
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=TEST;</property>
<property name="connection.username">sa</property>
<!-- Encryption -->
<property name="connection.password">ENC(vMO/j5jfpaU2cUhPVoOk5Q==)</property>
<property name="connection.provider_class">org.jasypt.hibernate4.connectionprovider.EncryptedPasswordDriverManagerConnectionProvider</property>
<property name="connection.encryptor_registered_name">hibernateEncryptor</property>
```

Then in the `HiberanteUtil.java` I have this

```
// Builds session factory.
private static SessionFactory configureSessionFactory() 
    throws HibernateException {

  Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
  StandardPBEStringEncryptor encryptor =
      new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
  encryptor.setPassword("pass");

  HibernatePBEEncryptorRegistry registry =
      HibernatePBEEncryptorRegistry.getInstance();

  registry.registerPBEStringEncryptor("hibernateEncryptor", encryptor);

  ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
      .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();

  return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
}
```

I've created the encrypted password with `encrypt.bat`.

Then the error i have is

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user
>   'sa'. ClientConnectionId:8033573f-5f52-4fe9-a728-fbe4f57d89c4

If I remove this part

```
StandardPBEStringEncryptor encryptor =
        new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
encryptor.setPassword("someKey");
HibernatePBEEncryptorRegistry registry =
        HibernatePBEEncryptorRegistry.getInstance();

registry.registerPBEStringEncryptor(
        "hibernateEncryptor", encryptor);
```

I have the same error, so I think it doesn't register but I have no idea how to do it.

This is how i encrypt

[image: jasypt problem image]

**UPDATE**

The only thing i can made to get it work is something like this, but is not the way i think.

```
StandardPBEStringEncryptor encryptor =
                new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
        encryptor.setPassword("somePass");
        encryptor.setAlgorithm("PBEWITHMD5ANDDES");
        String pass=encryptor.decrypt("HhpmA/XmJoLro8TYYu4YyA==");
        HibernatePBEEncryptorRegistry registry =
                HibernatePBEEncryptorRegistry.getInstance();
        registry.registerPBEStringEncryptor(
                "hibernateEncryptor", encryptor);

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure()
                .setProperty("hibernate.connection.encryptor_registered_name","hibernateEncryptor")
                .setProperty("hibernate.connection.password",pass);
```

So i think the problem is with the `"hibernateEncryptor"`, i think i need to register

```
  <typedef name="encryptedString" class="org.jasypt.hibernate4.type.EncryptedStringType">
   <param name="encryptorRegisteredName">hibernateEncryptor</param>
  <typedef>
```

But when i put it in `hibernate.cfg.xml`  says invalid mapping, so i add it to a class with annotation but nothing happen cause i think this is read after database connection that is what i want to encrypt. :(

```
@TypeDef(name="encryptedString",typeClass=org.jasypt.hibernate4.type.EncryptedStringType.class,
        parameters= {@Parameter(name="encryptorRegisteredName",value="hibernateEncryptor")})
```

Comment: Can you specify Hibernate version and Jasypt version?

Comment: @Haim `hibernate-4.1` and `jasypt 1.9.1` `jasypt-hibernate4-1.91`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not the proper way to do it but solves.

```
StandardPBEStringEncryptor encryptor =new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
encryptor.setPassword("somePass");
encryptor.setAlgorithm("PBEWITHMD5ANDDES");
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
String pass=encryptor.decrypt(configuration.getProperty("hibernate.connection.password"));
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password",pass);
```

And in `hibernate.cfg`

```
    <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
    <property name="connection.password">Nzuyhu5PJJwsVH3mdw==</property>
```

Answer (score 2):

You might try this:

```
StandardPBEStringEncryptor strongEncryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
strongEncryptor.setPassword("jasypt");
strongEncryptor.setAlgorithm("PBEWITHMD5ANDDES");
HibernatePBEEncryptorRegistry registry =                          HibernatePBEEncryptorRegistry.getInstance();
registry.registerPBEStringEncryptor("strongHibernateStringEncryptor", strongEncryptor);

Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", strongEncryptor.decrypt(configuration.getProperty("hibernate.connection.password")));
ServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistryBuilder.buildServiceRegistry());
```

Comment: +1 Actually, is similar what im doing but you take approach of getting via xml the property so you can change without rebuilding.. `HibernatePBEEncryptor` is not necessary if you do in that way.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jasypt.org/hibernate.html

Why not switch algorithms to:   PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES

Take a look at this post on StackOverflow:   [Error implementing Jasypt with Hibernate 3 and Struts 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291442/error-implementing-jasypt-with-hibernate-3-and-struts-2)