# Hibernate + Jasypt : Unable to resolve name ... as strategy

Tags: java, hibernate, jasypt

I'm trying to use Jasypt to encrypt the DB password in the **hibernate.cfg.xml** file in my application.

I'm currently using Hibernate **4.3.2** with Jasypt 1.9.2.


The following is my configuration : 


***hibernate.cfg.xml***

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Security  -->
        <property name="connection.provider_class">org.jasypt.hibernate.connectionprovider.EncryptedPasswordDriverManagerConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="connection.encryptor_registered_name">configurationHibernateEncryptor</property>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:db/pappu;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE</property>
        <property name="connection.username">pappu</property>
        <property name="connection.password">ENC(xsIYbIfGoS2mZ1Tokihdathbuk0JVS2A)</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">managed</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup - REMOVE THIS LINE FOR PRODUCTION-->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <!-- Mappings -->

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

***a part of HibernateUtil.java***

```
        try {
             StandardPBEStringEncryptor strongEncryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
             HibernatePBEEncryptorRegistry registry = HibernatePBEEncryptorRegistry.getInstance();
             strongEncryptor.setAlgorithm("PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES");
             strongEncryptor.setPassword("test");
             registry.registerPBEStringEncryptor("configurationHibernateEncryptor", strongEncryptor);       

             Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure("/pappu/config/hibernate.cfg.xml");         
             StandardServiceRegistryBuilder sb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
             sb.applySettings(cfg.getProperties());
             StandardServiceRegistry standardServiceRegistry = sb.build();      

             return cfg.buildSessionFactory(standardServiceRegistry);          
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
```

When I launch my application I get these errors :

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at pappu.core.db.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:60)
    at pappu.core.db.HibernateUtil.initSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:98)
    at pappu.core.db.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:70)
    at pappu.core.db.HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession(HibernateUtil.java:82)
    at pappu.Main.start(Main.java:23)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:197)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
    at pappu.core.db.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:56)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate connection provider [org.jasypt.hibernate.connectionprovider.EncryptedPasswordDriverManagerConnectionProvider]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:197)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.initiateService(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.initiateService(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:223)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.jasypt.hibernate.connectionprovider.EncryptedPasswordDriverManagerConnectionProvider] as strategy [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:194)
    ... 29 more
```

jasypt-1.9.2.jar and jasypt-hibernate4-1.9.2.jar are correctly included in the class path.

There is something weird, in [the tutorial provided by jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/hibernate.html), they use this property in their **hibernate.cfg.xml** :

```
<property name="connection.provider_class">
      org.jasypt.hibernate4.connectionprovider.EncryptedPasswordDriverManagerConnectionProvider
</property>
```

You can see the difference with my **hibernate.cfg.xml** at the line 8, I'm using

```
org.jasypt.hibernate.connectionprovider.EncryptedPasswordDriverManagerConnectionProvider
```

If I use the "org.jasypt.hibernate4.connectionprovider...." I get these errors :

```
juin 17, 2014 12:44:43 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
juin 17, 2014 12:44:43 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.2.Final}
juin 17, 2014 12:44:43 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
juin 17, 2014 12:44:43 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
juin 17, 2014 12:44:43 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /pappu/config/hibernate.cfg.xml
juin 17, 2014 12:44:43 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /pappu/config/hibernate.cfg.xml
juin 17, 2014 12:44:43 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
juin 17, 2014 12:44:43 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider
INFO: HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.jasypt.hibernate4.connectionprovider.EncryptedPasswordDriverManagerConnectionProvider
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/service/jdbc/connections/internal/DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at pappu.core.db.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:60)
    at pappu.core.db.HibernateUtil.initSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:98)
    at pappu.core.db.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:70)
    at pappu.core.db.HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession(HibernateUtil.java:82)
    at pappu.Main.start(Main.java:23)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/service/jdbc/connections/internal/DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:222)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.initiateService(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.initiateService(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:197)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
    at pappu.core.db.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:56)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 49 more
```

I'm totally lost because my **HibernateUtil.java** includes **org.jasypt.hibernate4** !

Comment: You must use org.jasypt.hibernate4.connectionprovider.EncryptedPasswordDriverManagerConnectionProvider as it is an actually class

Comment: If you are getting a ClassNotFoundException, then jasypt-hibernate4-1.9.2.jar cannot be on your classpath.

Comment: @JamesB I edited my post to show you the complete "ClassNotFoundException" log

Comment: The exception would suggest you haven't got all the required Hibernate jars on your classpath

Comment: The class `org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl` seems to be absent of the 4.3.2 version of Hibernate !

Comment: I have added an answer which I think solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that jasypt is looking for the class

> org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProvider‌​Impl

which is no longer available for versions of Hibernate 4.3.x and above.

Try reverting to Hibernate 4.2.13.Final and retry.

Comment: For the moment, I'm not totally satisfied with this solution because Hibernate has a more important role than Jasypt in my app and I only need to encrypt the db password. I used this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636547/cannot-encrypt-password-in-configuration-file). I will maybe have to encrypt the data in the database, therefore I will come back later on this post and review again your proposition if I have the same problem.